# SGD Optimizer NAN Loss

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I am working on a regression type problem. When if run to train the model i am facing the following outputs. Is there any problem in my code?
I also used adam, it gives numeric loss and mean_absolute_error.

```
Train on 2753307 samples, validate on 28094 samples
    Epoch 1/50
    1218816/2753307 [============>.................] - ETA: 47s - loss: nan - mean_absolute_error: nan
```

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050397/deep-learning-nan-loss-reasons look into the possible reasons...

Comment: This could be a couple of things. Could you post your code as well?